# How to examine the structure of Graphics objects

Tags: plotting, graphics

One difficulty I'm encountering in studying the structure of `Graphics` objects is that I have not yet found a way to print or display such structures that are sufficiently general.

The `FullForm` of `Graphics` objects can be huge and extremely difficult to take in visually.  I have tried to deal with this using `Shallow`, but with only limited success, because I find that "the interesting bits" in a `Graphics` not always occur at the same depth.

It's a chicken-and-egg problem: to write a function that displays such structure in a useful way, I need to understand what such structure could be.  But gaining this understanding is precisely what I'm trying to do here!

In case it matters, I'm primarily interested in examining the structure of `Graphics` objects generated, directly or indirectly, by plotting commands such as `Plot`, `ListPlot`, etc.

Comment: LOoking for things like this? `Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}][[1]] /. 
 l_List /; Length[l] > 5 :> Short[l]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Structure of Graphics (esp. those produced by Plot, ListPlot, etc.)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32712/structure-of-graphics-esp-those-produced-by-plot-listplot-etc)

Comment: @ssch: yes, exactly.  That one is very nice, BTW, thank you!

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28099/61) by MichaelE2 is very educational too.

Comment: @Hector: this post is definitely motivated by the same situation as the one you link to, but it is *not* a duplicate.  Here I'm asking about displaying techniques.  For all I know, there exists a black-box Mathematica function that would be a perfect answer to this question, without shedding any direct light on the question in that other post.

Comment: `(plot // First) /. List[(_?NumericQ) ..] :> Sequence[]` used there - [reducing quality...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32555/5478)

Comment: Related: "[Making customized InputForm and ShortInputForm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230478/590388)."

Comment: You could also addapt the tools provided in [(29339)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29339/121)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally, the following code gives you an interactive tree. You might want to enlarge the area of the tree if the nodes are too small.

```
structureOfGraph[gr_] := Module[{xx = gr /. Rule[a_, _] :> a /. 
  x_ /; And @@ NumericQ /@ x :> x[[0]] /. {List ..} :> 
  ListOfLists}, Manipulate[TreeForm[xx, n], {n, 1, Depth[xx] - 1, 1}]];

structureOfGraph[Show[Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}], Graphics[{Circle[]}]]]
```

---

**Second iteration**

This second attempt makes an even shorter tree by getting rid of the terminal `List`:

```
TreeForm[Graphics[{Blue, {EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Disk[]}, 
 Disk[{1, 0}]}] /. x_ /; And @@ NumericQ /@ x :> x[[0]] /. x_[List] :> x]
```

[image]

---

**First iteration**

I will send this as an answer because I cannot add comments with graphics to [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32718/8803).

```
TreeForm[Graphics[{Blue, {EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Disk[]}, 
Disk[{1, 0}]}] /. x_ /; And @@ NumericQ /@ x :> x[[0]]]
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Extremely cool, many thanks!

Comment: Can it be improved to have the `Part` number as `Tooltip`?

Comment: @P.Fonseca: probably yes. I would use MapIndexed.

Answer (score 20):

In light of the [structure of `Graphics`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32717/52), the best bet is to write a parser.  Here is one I wrote. It is not complete, as I keep discovering directives I've missed, but it is close.

```
(* Utility for turning printing on/off. *)
(* --- Mr.Wizard's version of BlockPrint --- *)
ClearAll[BlockPrint];
SetAttributes[BlockPrint, HoldRest];
BlockPrint[True , body_] := Block[{Print}, body]
BlockPrint[False, body_] := body

(* Parser proper. Invoked by: parser@Graphics[...] *)
ClearAll[parser, parser`iparser, parser`directive, parser`primitive]; 

Options[parser] = {Verbose -> False};
parser[a_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
Block[{parser`state = {}, parser`primList, parser`unknownfcn},
    parser`unknownfcn[_]:= Sequence[];
    BlockPrint[!OptionValue[Verbose], 
      Flatten[parser`iparser[a]] /. parser`primList -> List
    ] 
]

(* Better isolation*)
Begin["parser`"];

(* Note the changes for v10 *)
directive := _AbsolutePointSize | _Arrowheads | _CapForm | _Dashing | 
  _EdgeForm | _FaceForm | _Glow  | _JoinForm | 
  _Opacity | _PointSize |  _Specularity | _Thickness |
  If[ $VersionNumber < 10,
    _CMYKColor | _RGBColor | _GrayLevel | _Hue,
    _?ColorQ
  ];

primitive := _Arrow | _BezierCurve | _BSplineCurve | _BSplineSurface | _Circle | 
  _Cone | _Cuboid | _Cylinder | _Disk | _FilledCurve | _Inset | 
  _JoinedCurve | _Line | _Point | _Polygon | _Raster | _Raster3D | 
  _Rectangle | _Sphere | _Text | _Tube | 
  If[ $VersionNumber >= 10,
    _Ball | _Circumsphere | 
    _ConicHullRegion | _HalfLine | 
    _HalfPlane | _Hexahedron | _InfiniteLine  | 
    _Parallelepiped | _Parallelogram | _Prism | _Pyramid | 
    _Simplex | _Tetrahedron | _Triangle,
   ##&[]
  ] | 
  If[ $VersionNumber >= 10.2,
    _AffineHalfSpace | _AffineSpace | _Annulus | _CapsuleShape | 
    _Cuboid | _DiskSegment | _HalfSpace | _Hyperplane | _InfinitePlane | 
    _Insphere | _RegularPolygon | _SphericalShell | _StadiumShape,
    ##&[]
  ];

(* 
 AASTriangle, ASATriangle, SASTriangle, and SSSTriangle evaluate
 to Triangle via DownValues, so they'll never show up in Graphics(3D)
 by themselves.
*)

iparser[l_Legended] := iparser@First@l
iparser[g:(_Graphics|_Graphics3D)]:= iparser @ First @ g

iparser[{}]:= Sequence[]

iparser[l_List] := 
Internal`InheritedBlock[{state},
  Print["List"];
  iparser /@ l 
]

iparser[Style[a_, b__]]:=
Internal`InheritedBlock[{state,unknownfcn},
  (* augment unknown function to work with strings *)
  unknownfcn[str_String]:= (state = {state, str}; ##&[]);
  Print["Style"];
  iparser /@ {b};
  iparser @ a
]

iparser[GraphicsGroup[a_List]] := 
  (Print["GraphicsGroup - List"]; iparser @ a)
iparser[GraphicsGroup[a_]]:= 
  (Print["GraphicsGroup - NoList"]; iparser @ {a})

iparser[g_GraphicsComplex]:= 
  (Print["GraphicsComplex - Normalizing."]; iparser @ Normal @ g);

iparser[Directive[a___]] := 
  (Print["Directive: ", Directive[a]]; iparser /@ Flatten[{a}])

iparser[m:directive] := 
  (Print["directive: ", m]; state = {state, m}; ##&[])

iparser[p:primitive] := 
  (
   Print["primitive: ", p, "; state: ", state]; 
   (* Prevents flattening later *)
   primList[Flatten[state], p]
  )

iparser[a_] := (Print["unknown: ", a]; unknownfcn[a])
End[]; (* parser` *)
```

This returns a list of the form

```
{{{directives__}, primitive_} .. }
```

So, it can not be immediately used again in a `Graphics` object, but that can be sidestepped if need be.  Applying `parser` to the example from the previous question

```
parser@Graphics[{Blue, {EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Disk[]}, Disk[{1,0}]}]
```

returns

```
{
 {{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], EdgeForm[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[Large]}]}, Disk[{0, 0}]}, 
 {{RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, Disk[{1, 0}]}
}
```

as I described.

Comment: Heavy duty.  This could be very useful.  Have you tested it much?  I take it you wrote this before this question was asked?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've been tinkering with it on and off for a little bit with the main changes being the primitive/directive lists. It has two flaws. First, I'm not handling `Style` right, but I don't know what to do with named styles. Second, it doesn't recurse into `Inset`, so it only goes so deep.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard looking at it, I don't think I'm treating `GraphicsGroup` entirely correctly. For instance, `GraphicsGroup[Red]` would leak in my parser, yet it is fully contained in `Graphics`. I have not encountered that form in live code, so I don't think it is an issue, but should be fixed. There is an apparent flaw like it for `GraphicsComplex`, but `Normal@GraphicsComplex[...]` returns a list. So, that processing takes over.

Comment: I added a simpler version of `BlockPrint` in an answer below.  I think it would be more typical to handle "verbose" with Messages.  Is there a reason you `Print` instead?

Comment: I note the use and blocking of global variables.  I suppose you did this for simplicity but that could cause problems.  Shouldn't the entire thing be wrapped in a `Module` to localize these, e.g. `q`?

Comment: I need to sleep.  I hope I can dig into this code with you another time.

Comment: Your implementation of `BlockPrint` is a little cleaner. As to why `Print`: debugging. `Messages` are a pain. Sure, `q` could be localized like that, but more simply, it should be in a package. My general use for it is very simple, and I usually don't have to worry about invalidating user code when working with it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard fixed the problem with `GraphicsGroup` and renamed `q` to `primList` for a little clarity. Have you figured out how it works, yet? :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard a colleague pointed out I didn't handle `Legended`, so it is now fixed. Also, put the guts inside the ``parser` `` context to better isolate the code. Lastly, I conceded your point on `BlockPrint`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a `Graphics` explorer that enables you to see the hierarchy of the `Graphics` statement while allowing you to open and close parts for clarity. Large graphics primitives (with 'large' I mean with lots of coordinates) are replaced with their graphical equivalents to make it a bit more compact and recognizable.

Test graphics:

```
plot = 
  Show[
    Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}], 
    Graphics[{Circle[]}], 
    Graphics@GraphicsComplex[{{10, 0}, {10, 1}, {9, 0}, {10, -1}}, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]
  ]
```

There we go:

```
graphicsExplorer[plot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A part of the `Graphics` structure can now be easily indexed using the printed level indications. For instance, the `Hue` statement in the picture above is:

```
plot[[1, 1, 1, 3, 1]]
```

> Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]

The code:

```
ClearAll[graphicsExplorer];
graphicsExplorer[expr_] := graphicsExplorer[expr, 0, False];
graphicsExplorer[expr_, d_, gc_] :=
 Module[{h = Head[expr]},
  If[AtomQ[expr],
   Row[{d, "\[Rule]", expr}, " "],
   If[MatchQ[h, 
      Line | Polygon | Point | Arrow | Tube | BezierCurve | BSplineCurve | BSplineSurface] && 
     StringLength[ToString@expr] > 50,
    Row[{d, "\[Rule]", h, 
      Graphics[If[gc === False, expr, GraphicsComplex[gc, expr]], AspectRatio -> 1/5]}, " "],
    Framed@
     OpenerView[{Row[{d, "\[Rule]", Tooltip[h, expr]}, " "], 
       Column[MapIndexed[
         graphicsExplorer[#1, #2[[1]], 
           If[h === GraphicsComplex, expr[[1]], gc]] &, (expr /. h -> List)]]}]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

A `Tooltip` provides a bit of context at every level.

For 3D graphics define a `graphics3DExplorer` in which every `Graphics` in the code is replaced by `Graphics3D`.

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you so much for posting this!

Comment: It's a situation that happens to me often in Mathematica SE, and more generally, cases in which I would like to accept more than one answer...

Answer (score 7):

A streamlined version of Hector's "Second iteration" method:

```
simple = TreeForm[# //. h_[List .. | __?NumericQ] :> h] &;
```

Use:

```
Graphics[{Blue, {EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Disk[]}, Disk[{1, 0}]}] // simple
```

[image]

---

rcollyer's `BlockPrint` can be simplified:

```
SetAttributes[BlockPrint, HoldRest];
BlockPrint[False , body_] := Block[{Print}, body]
BlockPrint[True, body_] := body
```

I'll try to streamline the rest of his parser, once I understand it. :^)

Comment: Thanks!  Trees are definitely an appealing for this task.  It turns out, however, that for the `Graphics` objects I need most help with (namely, those generated by plotting commands like `Plot`), the standard `TreeForm` layout doesn't work: these trees have too many nodes at the same level, hence many node labels get obscured by the other ones.  A *conceptually* simple fix would be to rotate the layout of the nodes (while keeping labels horizontal), but this is surprisingly difficult to do (at least for me).  I posted a [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32727/2464) about it,...

Comment: ...and got several replies, but it was the same problem all over again: these solutions work fine with simple examples but fail with the trees I want to visualize.  What's worse, they all fail in utterly baffling ways, and this bizarreness of behavior greatly cooled my enthusiasm for this line of attack.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: "A streamlined version of Hector's …" what do you have against quick and dirty? You've been "streamlining" my answers for some time now! … Thank you. Your post taught me about the `?` for patterns.

Comment: @Hector I sort of obsessively optimize syntax; I can't help myself.  I figure I might as well share the results.  I take it from "Thank you" that you don't mind; I hope this is the case.  If you are learning about `?` (`PatternTest`) be sure to read these:  [(1835)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121), [(1699)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1699/121), [(30425)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/121)

Comment: You've got the conditions in `BlockPrint` backwards, when `True`, `Print` should not be blocked, and vice verse. Fixing ...

Comment: @rcollyer lol -- well, it was the way *I* would write it:  `Block` `Print` when `BlockPrint` is `True`.  Isn't that logical? :-p

Comment: Supremely, that's why I didn't catch it until I ran it. It's intent is to turn `Print` on and off, i.e. `True` and `False`.

Comment: @rcollyer Perhaps the function should be called something else then, like `verbose` or `withPrinting`?

Comment: It was originally called `VerboseBlock`, but I thought `BlockPrint` was more clear.

Answer (score 3):

When just looking for the structure all data is mostly noise, here is a way to strip out all lists that just contains numbers:

```
plot = Show[Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}], Graphics[{Circle[]}]]
DeleteCases[
 plot[[1]],
 _List?(VectorQ[Flatten[#], NumericQ] &),
 Infinity]
(* {{{
     {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Line[]},
     {Hue[0.906068, 0.6, 0.6], Line[]}
    }}, {Circle[{0, 0}]}} *)
```

`VectorQ[Flatten[#], NumericQ]` matches all lists of all shapes that contains only numbers unlike `ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ]` it is True also for `{{1},2}` etc.

`Circle[{0,0}]` is in the output because after `{0,0}` is taken away `Circle[]` automatically evaluates back to `Circle[{0,0}]`