# Can TreeForm be displayed "sideways"?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, trees

One recurrent problem I'm having with displays generated with `TreeForm` is that the expressions to be so displayed often at least one level with many (> 20) nodes at, which results in many overlapping labels that obscure each other.<sup>1</sup>

One simple way to mitigate the problem would be to display the same tree "sideways" (i.e., rotated 90 degrees, as would be the case if the display had been generated by a `TreePlot` command with the `Left` orientation parameter, for example).  Of course, for this strategy to be at all useful, it is necessary that only the geometrical arrangement of the nodes and edges be rotated, *not* the labels.  The latter should remain in the standard "horizontal"/left-to-right/text orientation.

I'm stymied by the fact that the output of `TreeForm` only *looks* like a `Graphics` object, but isn't really one.  Is there a way to get Mathematica to return the `Graphics` object corresponding to the displayed image?  Better yet would be to get the equivalent `TreePlot` command.

**EDIT:**

<sup>1</sup> For example, the following shows the kind of tree I'm trying to work with:

```
g = Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
         PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}];
TreeForm[g /. x_ /; And @@ NumericQ /@ x :> x[[0]] /. x_[List] :> x]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the output of TreeForm only looks like a `Graphics` object, but isn't really one."? It is made up of graphics primitives... Did you mean to say it looks like a `Graph` object, but isn't one?

Comment: @rm-rf: Maybe I'm not interpreting what I'm seeing correctly, but if I run `TreeForm[x+y]`, and then run `FullForm[%]`, what I get is `Plus[x, y]`, and not `Graphics[...]`.  This suggests that `TreeForm` does not really produce a `Graphics` object, but is merely a display directive...  Again, I may not be interpreting what I'm seeing correctly...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**ExpressionTreePlot**
(update, thanks to @Belisarius)

The `` GraphUtilities` `` package contains a function that will do the trick:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
ExpressionTreePlot[1+Sin[x^2], Left]
```

[image: ExpressionTreePlot screenshot]

**ExprTreePlot**
(my original response)

If you do not mind using an undocumented function, then `` Network`GraphPlot`ExprTreePlot `` can do the job:

```
Network`GraphPlot`ExprTreePlot[1+Sin[x^2], Left]
```

[image: ExprTreePlot screenshot]

The arguments to this function are:

```
ExprTreePlot[expr_, orientation_:Top, maxlevel_:Infinity, format_:StandardForm, options___]
```

Of course, all the usual caveats apply: there is no official support, the feature may be removed from future versions, etc.  But it gives us convenient access to all the usual choices for root node placement:

```
Table[
  Network`GraphPlot`ExprTreePlot[1+Sin[x^2], orientation]
, {orientation , {Left, Right, Top, Bottom, Center}}
] // GraphicsColumn[#, ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}, Frame -> All]&
```

[image: ExprTreePlot screenshot]

**Recovering the `TreePlot`**

As an alternative, we could extract the `TreePlot` generated by `TreeForm`.  The complication is that `TreeForm` is an inert wrapper.  The generation of the `TreePlot` happens when the front-end creates the box form.  The good news is that we can use `MakeBoxes` to extract the `TreePlot` in held form:

```
Block[{TreePlot}
, t_TreePlot := Throw @ Hold @ t
; Catch @ MakeBoxes @ TreeForm[1+Sin[x^2]]
]

(*
Hold[TreePlot[
{{"Plus","0","         2\n1 + Sin[x ]"}->{"1","1","1"},...},
Top,
{"Plus","0","         2\n1 + Sin[x ]"},
AlignmentPoint->Center,
AspectRatio->Automatic,
...]]
*)
```

Beware that the recovered `TreePlot` expression may use undocumented constructs that generate (harmless) warnings.  Such warnings are normally muffled by the front-end's box generation process.

Comment: I've added a section on how to recover the `TreePlot`.

Comment: I've simplified the code used to recover the `TreePlot`.

Comment: I think it's documented here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GraphUtilities/tutorial/GraphUtilities.html

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for the pointer... I've updated my response.

Comment: @WReach, as of M10, ExpressionTreePlot is deprecated: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphUtilities/ref/ExpressionTreePlot.html

Comment: @alancalvitti Thanks for the pointer.  The docs say that the functionality has been moved to the core system, but I see no sign of it in the WolframCloud.  I'll try to remember to check V10 when it comes out and update my response accordingly.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a possible way, using `TreeForm` directly, and with `VertexRenderingFunction`. I think this is what you describe in your second paragraph. I hope this is useful to you

```
TreeForm[1 + Sin[x^2], 
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[Panel@Rotate[#2, -π/2], #1] &)] //
    Rotate[#, π/2] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Similar to Pinguin Dirk answer but with the standard style

```
RotatedTreeForm[x_] := 
  Rotate[TreeForm[x, 
    VertexRenderingFunction -> (Rotate[
        Inset[Framed[Style[#2, "StandardForm", "Output", 
           FontSize -> Scaled[0.1]], Background -> LightYellow, 
          FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5]], #1], -\[Pi]/2] &)], \[Pi]/2];

Cos[Exp[x]] // RotatedTreeForm
```

[image]

Comment: you know, I love `Panel`, I guess I use it way too often :)

Comment: @ybeltukov Nice solution, but it should be noted that one needs to count from bottom to top, which is counter intuitive. For example, e has the coordinate {1,1} and Plus - {1,2}

Answer (score 5):

[Version 12.3](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn123.html) added the experimental function [`ExpressionTree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionTree.html) to convert an expression to a [`Tree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tree.html) object.  [Version 13](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn130.html) added the [`TreeLayout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeLayout.html) option that can be used to specify the root position.  In [version 14](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn140.html), the tree is automatically reflected so that the children are always ordered left-to-right or top-to-bottom, as appropriate.  [Version 13.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn131.html) added the [`TreeElementLabelFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeElementLabelFunction.html) option which can be used to apply a function to the data to generate the label; e.g. [`Shallow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shallow.html).  And [version 13.2](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn132.html) added the [`MaxDisplayedChildren`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn132.html) option to limit the number of children to display.

Here's a simple example of `ExpressionTree`:

```
ExpressionTree[1 + Sin[x^2], TreeLayout -> Left]
```

[image: ExpressionTree of one plus sine of x squared with root position Left]

Here's a more complicated example using these options to manage the complexity:

```
g = Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}];

ExpressionTree[g, TreeLayout -> Left, 
 TreeElementLabelFunction -> All -> (data |-> Shallow[data, 2]), 
 MaxDisplayedChildren -> All -> 3, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: ExpressionTree of a complicated Plot]

Answer (score 4):

Using the undocumented function `` SparseArray`ExpressionToTree ``

```
expr = 1 + Sin[x^2];
ett = SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[expr];
(* {{Plus,0,1+Sin[x^2]}->{1,1,1},
   {Plus,0,1+Sin[x^2]}->{Sin,2,Sin[x^2]},
   {Sin,2,Sin[x^2]}->{Power,3,x^2},
   {Power,3,x^2}->{x,4,x},
   {Power,3,x^2}->{2,5,2}}*)

edges = ett[[All, All, 1]];
(* {Plus->1,Plus->Sin,Sin->Power,Power->x,Power->2} *)

Graph[edges, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Center, Center}],
  VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .12}, VertexLabelStyle -> 20,
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle",
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> edges[[1, 1]],"Orientation" -> Left},
  ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Note: This works in Version 9.0.1.0.

Comment: [See also](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51645/13017) (for people like me who coincidentally saw the question 3 days after this answer was posted)