# Horizontal Tree Layout?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I need to display arbitrary *Expressions* in `TreeForm,` but the standard vertical layout produces too many horizontally overlapping boxes.  Am I doomed to rewriting expressions as graphs and using `TreePlot` and `GraphPlot` and going down this road

http://www.wolfram.com/technology/guide/FullyAutomatedGraphLayout/

or is there something I can do in a hurry to make `TreeForm` look better?

Docs say

```
TreeForm takes the same options as TreePlot.
```

so I pop over to `TreePlot` and see

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 4, 1 -> 6, 1 -> 8, 2 -> 6, {3 -> 8, "3\[Rule]8"}, 
  4 -> 5, 7 -> 8}, Left]
```

go back to `TreeForm` and try

```
TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d, Left]
```

but oops:

```
TreeForm::tlev: Warning: level specification Left is not a non-negative integer or
Infinity; ignored. >>
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Can TreeForm be displayed “sideways”?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32727/484)

Comment: Left is not an option,  it's a parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally - arbitrary-angle layout:

```
Rotate[ ... /. x_Framed -> Rotate[x, -angle], angle]
```

[image]

Now you can do it like this:

```
Rotate[ToExpression@ToBoxes@TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d] /. 
  x_Framed -> Rotate[x, -Pi/2], Pi/2]
```

Or like this:

[image]

P.S. =========================

Manipulate code for the record

```
Manipulate[Show[Rasterize@
   Rotate[ToExpression@ToBoxes@TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d] /. 
     x_Framed -> Rotate[x, -ang], ang],
  ImageSize -> 200 {1, 1}],
 {ang, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: ouch...totally ignored `Rotate`. yes, that makes absolutely sense.

Comment: This is a really good instance of "thinking out of the box" -- composing some generic but display-specific functions (/slaps forehead)

Comment: Interesting that the Rotate works when the TreeForm graphic is pasted directly into the Rotate call, but the following does not work (because it doesn't rotate the internal framed bits) `Rotate[TreeForm[a+b^2+c^3+d], /. x_Framed -> Rotate[Framed[x], -Pi/2], Pi/2]`

Comment: This code adds an extra frame. You only need `Rotate[ ... /. x_Framed -> Rotate[x, -Pi/2], Pi/2]`

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens thank you, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is by any means what you're looking for, but you can use
`VertexCoordinateRules` to determine the coordinates at which vertices should be placed:

```
TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d, 
    VertexCoordinateRules -> {{1, 4}, {2, 8}, {3, 8}, {4, 10}, {4, 6}, {3, 0}, 
        {4, 3}, {4, -2}, {2, 0}}]
```

[image]