# Graphics in Notebook Different from Graphics Expression?

Tags: graphics, front-end, evaluation, conversion

Consider the expression

```
TreeForm[a+b^2+c^3+d]
```

which displays as

[image]

This is a nice Graphics object, as I can prove by typing `//FullForm` after it, like this

[image]

and getting

```
Graphics[Annotation[
  GraphicsComplex[
   List[List[1.29777, 1.29777], List[0., 0.648886], 
   List[0.648886, 0.648886], List[0.324443, 0.], List[0.973329, 0.], 
   List[1.94 
... 
    List[Tooltip[
      Inset[Framed[Style[Plus, "StandardForm", "Output", Rule[LineColor,
```

It has framed elements in it, as I can prove by either looking at the text above, or by typing

[image]

But, the `TreeForm` expression itself does not have any framed elements in it.  For instance

```
TreeForm[a+b^2+c^3+d] /. (x_Framed :> Print[x])
```

produces the original graphic

[image]

Somehow, the Notebook is not allowing me to capture and rewrite the expression form of the graphic -- the only way I know to access it is by cutting and pasting the graphical form of the object manually by mouse into the places where I need to manipulate it. This is no good. I need `SecretEvaluator`, such that

```
SecretEvaluator[TreeForm[a+b^2+c^3+d]] /. (x_Framed :> Print[x])
```

produces the same output as

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason your original code fails is that the `TreeFrom` object is only *formatted* as `Graphics` object, meaning that it converted for display rather that as part of the normal evaluation sequence.

You can convert to and from box form to recover your `Graphics` object:

```
tf = TreeForm[a + b^2 + c^3 + d];

gr = tf // ToBoxes // ToExpression

gr /. (x_Framed :> Print[x]);
```

[image]

Comment: `ToBoxes` and also `MakeBoxes` are the top-level clues to understanding how expressions are rendered and converted.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 7):

From [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32740/2490)

```
Network`GraphPlot`ExprTreePlot[a+b^2+c^3+d] /. (x_Framed :> Print[x])
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on swish's answer, I would write

```
nodes = Cases[Network`GraphPlot`ExprTreePlot[a + b^2 + c^3 + d], _Framed, ∞];
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to work with the individual node objects; for example:

```
nodes[[2]]
```

[image: a-node]

If want output that looks like your printed output just evaluate

```
Column@nodes
```

[image: all-nodes]