# How to replace Divide in an expression?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, semantic-matching

It seems that `a/b` is always replaced with the form: `a * b^-1`, `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`. I tried `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, `HoldAll` and this always happens.

Thus `a/b /. {Times -> Minus}` leads to `a - b^-1` and `any_expression /. {Divide -> Minus}` is always unchanged

How can I replace `Divide` in `a/b` with `Minus` to get `a-b`?

Comment: How about: `repl = Times[x_, Power[y_, -1]] -> x - y;` . For testing: `{a/b, c a/(b d)} //. repl`

Comment: This was asked before few times, you need to use the `FullForm` of the expression. But why not just do the following: `expr /. Numerator[expr]/Denominator[expr] -> 
  Numerator[expr] - Denominator[expr]`  where `expr` is your rational expression you show. This way you do not have to worry about it. Is the above the only example you are looking to change or you have more complicated cases? ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iikvz.png)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84908/1871

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't be surprised if there's a duplicate for this, but I can't find it, so let me write an answer. The following solution works on toy examples, but semanic-matching problem usually need to be studied case by case, so don't be surprised if it doesn't work well on your real problem:

```
divide…to…minus[expr_] := 
 ToBoxes@expr /. FractionBox[a_, b_] :> RowBox[{a, "-", b}] // ToExpression

(a d)/(b c) // divide…to…minus
(* -b c + a d *)
```

See the posts under the tag [semantic-matching](/questions/tagged/semantic-matching) for more info.