# How do I "evaluate in place" programmatically? Need to evaluate Defer[] result in non-interactive setting

Tags: programming, evaluation

I need to evaluate the result returned from an external package, which contains `Defer` in it, but do this in a script without user interaction.

I am not able to figure how to do this, without actually using the mouse and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> in the notebook itself. But I need to do this in a program (script) that runs outside the notebook environment.

Here is an example:

```
r = Defer[Integrate][Cos[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `out` cell there has the Defer in it. I want to now evaluate `r`.  The only way is by moving the mouse to the `Out` cell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which now changes the `Out` cell to an `In` cell and evaluate what was there resulting in:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I do the above in a script? I tried `Evaluate[r]` and `Evaluate[ReleaseHold[r]]` and all sorts of things. But I can't get rid of the `Defer`. (There is no `RemoveDefer` function). The only way is to do [evaluate in place](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/EvaluateInPlace.html) which is what the pointing on the cell and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> does.

How do I remove `Defer` from a returned expression and evaluate the result in non-interactive script (i.e. programmatically)?

I am using version 10.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: `r /. Defer -> Identity` ?

Comment: How about `r/.Defer->Identity` ? Wow, @ilian was 10 seconds faster!

Comment: Indeed, a photo-finish!

Comment: @ilian and jens thanks! Yes, this did the trick. I spend long time searching and never saw this trick. Please feel free to post this as answer if you like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by both me and [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens)

```
r = Defer[Integrate][Cos[x], x];
r /. Defer -> Identity
```

> ```
> Sin[x]
> ```

Comment: I wish Mathematica documentation for [Defer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) would mention such method. Nothing there that mentions how to evaluate `Defer` expressions other than evaluate in place method.

Answer (score 10):

[`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) is a special head that behaves like [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html), but it has an additional rule for output: it disappears from the output box expression.

There is nothing special about how it is handled as *input* -- all the "magic" takes place during output formatting. To emulate this process, simply apply a [`ToBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToBoxes.html) [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) pair:

```
r = Defer[Integrate][Cos[x], x];

r // ToBoxes // ToExpression
```

> Sin[x]

This is superior to a simple replacement of all instances of `Defer` with `Identity` as it replicates the output-input process, whereas replacement does not:

```
x = {Defer};
x /. Defer -> Identity
x // ToBoxes // ToExpression
```

> ```
> {Identity} 
>
> {Defer}
> ```

One could instead match the head `Defer`, i.e. `/. Defer[x_] :> x`, but if the desire is to replicate output and re-input I believe box conversion is the appropriate method. See for example:

- [Graphics in Notebook Different from Graphics Expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45808/)

Comment: Thanks for fixing my stupid typos @Peter !