# How do I prevent Root and RootSum from expanding over quadratic roots?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, undocumented

For cubic and higher order polynomials, `Root` and `RootSum` are generally left unevaluated:

```
RootSum[d + c #1 + b #1^2 + a #1^3 &, Cos[#1] &]
```

> ```
> RootSum[d + c #1 + b #1^2 + a #1^3 &, Cos[#1] &]
> ```

But for sum over roots of *quadratic* and lower order polynomials,

```
RootSum[a #^2 + b # + c &, Cos[#] &]
```

immediately turns into

> [image]

and also,

```
Root[a #^2 + b # + c &, 1]
Root[a #^2 + b # + c &, 2]
```

each immediately get turned into (`-` case for `1` and `+` case for `2`)

> [image]

This is bad for two reasons:

1. For numeric evaluation, forms that are output by `Root` are not the best (*e.g.* it is sometimes more stable to write the second root `x2` in terms of the first `x1` using `x2 -> c/a*1/x1`).
2. Analytically, if the coefficients `a`, `b`, `c` are generally complicated expressions, it is more compact and also more pleasant to the eye if the expression is left in `RootSum` or `Root` from.

**Question**:  How do I prevent the automatic expansion of `Root` and `RootSum` over quadratic roots, and force them to remain unevaluated/unexpanded like for higher order polynomials.

None of the evaluation control functions `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, `Inactive`... are acceptable here since they interfere with symbolic manipulation routines that would otherwise work without them, *e.g.*:

```
D[Inactive[RootSum][a #^2 + b # + c &, Cos[ω #] &], ω]
```

> [image]

The ideal solution would entail either setting specific options to `Root` or `RootSum` to prevent automatic expansion, or to modify (possibly undocumented) internal code associated with these functions.

Comment: Can you explain what form you would like the RootSum to appear in?

Comment: @bills I edited my question.  Essentially, I want `Root` and `RootSum` to remain unexpanded for generic quadratic and lower order polynomials.  *i.e* `RootSum[a #^2 + b # + c &, Cos[#] &]` should return unevaluated just as `RootSum[a #^3 + b #^2 + c # + d &, Cos[#] &]` is returned unevaluated.

Comment: It does not seem to do the expansion if the function is general -- i.e., `RootSum[d + c # + b #^2 &, f]` is not expanded.

Comment: I do not understand why, for instance, `Inactive` is unacceptable. `D[Inactive[RootSum][a #^2 + b # + c &, Cos[ω #] &], ω] // Activate` works well. The only downside I see is that `Inactive` needs to be applied in each operation.  It is for that reason only that I suggest `Defer` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The following may help.  According to its [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html), "`Defer[expr]` yields an object that displays as the unevaluated form of `expr`, but that is evaluated if it is explicitly given as Wolfram Language input."

```
Defer[RootSum[a #^2 + b # + c &, Cos[ω #] &]]

(* RootSum[a #1^2 + b #1 + c &, Cos[ω #1] &] *)
```

But,

```
D[%, ω] /. Defer'[_] -> 1

(* -(((-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c]) Sin[((-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c]) ω)/(2 a)])/(2 a)) 
   - ((-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c]) Sin[((-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c]) ω)/(2 a)])/(2 a) *)
```

as desired.

**Addendum**

A cleaner [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88631/1063), based on an answer by Mr.Wizard, is

```
D[%, ω] // ToBoxes // ToExpression
```