# How to label only leaves in TreeForm?

Tags: output-formatting, labeling

I have a Huffman encoding represented as a list in the following manner:

```
encoding = {{{w, d}, {o, s}}, {{{e, q}, a}, {i, j}}};
```

This means that `w` is encoded using $000$, `d` is encoded using $001$, `e` is encoded using $1000$, and so on. When I print the list in `TreeForm`, it looks like this:

[image: Huffman]

Which is pretty fine on its own right, *however*, I would want to label only the leaves and ignore the internal nodes which say `List`. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: A quick-and-dirty solution is `encoding /. List -> "" // TreeForm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `TreeForm` produces a `GraphPlot` and takes the same options as `GraphPlot`, it can be done by using a custom vertex rendering function.

```
encoding = {{{w, d}, {o, s}}, {{{e, q}, a}, {i, j}}};
TreeForm[encoding, 
  VertexRenderingFunction -> 
    (If[#2 === List, 
     Inset[Text["\[FilledCircle]"], #], 
     Inset[Framed[Text[Style[#2, 18]], Background -> White], #]] &)]
```

[image: tree]

Answer (score 6):

Just to add some diversity, although I think m_goldbergs answer is very convenient and should be used in most cases. Nevertheless, always remember that you can easily de-structure *Mathematica* expressions, even the box-expressions that are used for displaying things in the front end.

One possible way to start is to look at the box-expressions of a very simple tree, like this one

```
MakeBoxes[TreeForm[{a}]]
```

There, you see how the final view consists of a combination of various boxes. It only takes a short time to note that you probably want to replace the `StyleBox["List"..]` part and put a simple circle instead. Therefore,

```
encoding = {{{w, d}, {o, s}}, {{{e, q}, a}, {i, j}}};
(TreeForm[encoding] // MakeBoxes) /.
  FrameBox[StyleBox["List", ___], ___] :>
  GraphicsBox[{EdgeForm[{Thick, GrayLevel[0.5]}], 
  FaceForm[RGBColor[1., 1., 0.871]], DiskBox[{0, 0}]}, 
 ImageSize -> Scaled[20]] // ToExpression
```

And you are left with a very nice tree

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, you may wonder how on earth you should have known how to use `GraphicsBox` and all its content.

This is unfortunately a very difficult science called: *stealing*. So what you do is nothing more than draw a disk:

```
Graphics[Disk[]]
```

Then, you click on the output graphics and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or menu Cell -> Show Expression) and you see the underlying boxes. Add an `EdgeForm` and a `FaceForm` and steal the colors from your box-expression of the `TreeForm` and you are done. The image size option was a bit trial and error.

### Update for Mathematica 13

As an exercise to the reader: What did I change to make it work with Mathematica 13?

```
encoding = {{{w, d}, {o, s}}, {{{e, q}, a}, {i, j}}};
(TreeForm[encoding] // MakeBoxes)[[1]] /.
  FrameBox[StyleBox["List", ___], ___] :>
  GraphicsBox[{EdgeForm[{Thick, GrayLevel[0.5]}], 
  FaceForm[RGBColor[1., 1., 0.871]], DiskBox[{0, 0}]}, 
 ImageSize -> Scaled[20]] // ToExpression
```

Comment: @MarkAdler Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks! Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Using the function `` SparseArray`ExpressionToTree ``:

```
ClearAll[trF]
trF[s_: {0.01, .05}][e_, opts : OptionsPattern[Options[Graph]]] :=
 Module[{saett = SparseArray`ExpressionToTree[e], 
         edges, vertices, vsizes, labels, vlabels},
  edges = saett[[All, All, 2]];
  vertices = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ List @@@ edges];
  labels = ArrayPad[Replace[saett[[All, All, 1]][[All, 2]], List->"", 1], {1, 0}, ""];
  vlabels = Thread[vertices -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ labels)];
  vsizes = Thread[vertices -> (If[# === "", {"Scaled", s[[1]]}, 
                 {"Scaled", s[[2]]}] & /@ labels)];
  Graph[edges, VertexSize -> vsizes, VertexLabels -> vlabels, opts]]

trF[][encoding, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive["Subsection", Black], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also: [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51653/125)