# ContourPlot - plot only one connected component

Tags: plotting

How do I plot only one component in `ContourPlot` when specifying a height.

For example,

```
ContourPlot[
  Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Exp[-x^2 - y^2] == 0,
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}
]
```

produces concentric circles. How do I plot only the innermost one? That is the component going through (Pi,0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contour closest to point:

```
x0={Pi,0}

Normal@ContourPlot[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Exp[-x^2 - y^2] == 0, {x,-10,10}, {y,-10, 10},
                   PlotPoints -> 100
                  ] /. {x_, y__Line} :> {x, 
                       Line@SortBy[{y}[[;; , 1]], Min[Norm[# - x0] & /@ #] &][[1]]}
```

[image]

If you are aware of ther structure of graphics you can deal with such problems *ad hoc*:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Exp[-x^2 - y^2] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
            PlotPoints -> 100
           ] /. {col_, y__Line} :> {col, {y}[[-1]]}
```

That's not necessarily best way but the better network of information on SE the better! :)

So about the structure, you may want to take a look at:

[Examine structure of graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32716/5478)

Comment: How do you know which contour line this will be, other than testing?  Is is always the innermost for example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ofc not, best example is `Sin[x]==0` where it's hard to tell what is innermost. I suspected it should be first or last one. That's why I called it *ad hoc*. :) I've provided an explanation why this was posted, if it works, why not ;) maybe someone will learn something.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok, more general solution added. more convenient for not easy to set region functions.

Comment: This seems good - I'll need to play around with it a bit.

Comment: @pdmclean I'm glad you like it :) It is good to hold on with an accept a day or two, better answers may appear while now others may feel discouraged ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can add a [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionFunction.html):

```
ContourPlot[
  Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Exp[-x^2 - y^2] == 0,
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 5 < x^2 + y^2 < 15]
]
```

[image]

What the region itself looks like:

```
RegionPlot[5 < x^2 + y^2 < 15, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]