# Visualising Special Relativity

Tags: graphics, physics, differential-geometry

Mathematica newbie learning by doing (or not so far, in this case).

**Problem**: Special Relativity - consider two inertial frames $A$ & $A'$ in relative motion. At a time $t0$ as measured in $S$, draw a sphere $S'$ of radius $b$ in the hyperplane of simultaneity of $A'$ (i.e. orthogonal to $t'$), i.e. a surface that is spherical seen in $A'$ and exists only for the "moment" $t'0$. $t'0$ is simultanous with $t0$ as seen from $A$. (*I have the Lorentz transformation matrix ready; use `c=1` for simplicity*)

**Objectives**:

a) visualise $S$, the image of $S'$ as seen from $A$ as a function of time in $A$, ideally with some surface patterning (e.g. lat/long grid, colour gradients, etc.) on $S'$ that will be transformed along with $S'$ so that the appearance of the surface seen from $A$ is also meaningful (shows orientation, distortion, etc.)

b) determine analytically $tmin$ and $tmax$, the times at which the $S$ appears and disappears according to $A$ (see Expectatons below)

**Expectation**: I *think* $S$ becomes an ellipsoid that grows and shrinks betweem $tmin$ and $tmax$: since simultaneous events in $A'$ are not simultaneous in $A$ they must be at different times and continuity of the sphere implies a continuous temporal interval.  I am not sure which is harder: doing 4D geometry in one's head or trying to do it by programming [Mathematica]

Polite request for explicit code, if possible: at this stage I don't think I can be relied on to read between the lines - and if you wouldn't mind explaining how it works then I would also learn two things at once.

Thanks in advance

PS: It is not difficult to plot a sphere (thanks to Kuba for an nice way of doing that), the problem is producing a description (functions?) that can be both plotted and transformed so as to preserve surface features and to get the analytical answer b) above. I have looked at many Mathematic demonstrations and code, and tried too many graphics functions to list here and explain why they didn't seem to work for me - it's a completely open question: how would *you* do it?

**Code for generating the Lorentz matrix.**

NB you may notice special case handling for `v = 0` because *Mma* objected to `0/0` (and for `v>=c` returning a `0 matrix` because I don't know how to throw an error)

```
LorentzF[v_] := Module[{l, i, j, dim, γ},
   dim = Length[v] + 1;
   If[NumericQ[Norm[v]] == True  && (Norm[v] == 0  || Norm[v] >= 1),
    If[Norm[v] == 0,
     l = Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}],
     l = Table[0, {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}]],
    If[dim < 2, l = {},
     l = Table[0, {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}];
     l[[1, 1]] = γ;
     For[i = 2, i <= dim, i++, 
      l[[1, i]] = l[[i, 1]] = -γ v[[i - 1]]
      ];
     For[i = 2, i <= dim, i++, 
      For[j = 2, j <= dim, j++, 
       l[[i, j]] = 
        l[[j, i]] = (γ - 1) v[[i - 1]] v[[j - 1]]/ v.v + 
          KroneckerDelta[i, j]
       ]
      ]; 
     ]
    ];
   γ = 1/Sqrt[1 - v.v];
   l
   ];
```

**Bona fides**

Check that `-v` is the inverse

```
Simplify[LorentzF[{bx, by, bz}].LorentzF[-{bx, by, bz}]]  // MatrixForm
```

Pick out the spatial part [NB, this is physically wrong, but I'm showing willing]
creating something that can be used by `GeometricTransformation`

```
LorentzFSpace[{vx_, vy_, vz_}] :=  LorentzF[{vx, vy, vz}][[2 ;; 4]][[All, 2 ;; 4]]
```

Plot a sphere using `RegionPLot`

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Another attempt

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[Sphere[], LorentzFSpace[{0.56, 0.56, 0.56}]], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}} ]
```

But I can't "markup" `Sphere[]` or do a *proper* hyperplane intersection because only the presentation is being changed (and it's still the wrong transform)

Think about doing it by points and lines based upon a lat/long grid (which won't work for reasons given above) latdivs = # divisions of latitude to use, etc. NB, when I first entered the function below I used "=" instead of ":=" by mistake, which lead to a "Iterator does not have appropriate bounds" error on the inner iterator. I don't understand why that mistake had that effect.

```
sphereGrid4D[latdivs_, longdivs_, originpt_, radius_]  :=  Table[{originpt[[1]], originpt[[2]] + radius*sin[i 2 Pi/longdivs], originpt[[3]] + radius*cos[i 2 Pi/ longdivs], originpt[[4]] - radius*sin[j Pi /latdivs]}, {j, 0, longdivs}, {i, 0, latdivs}]
```

Kuba's contribution (on the question they suggested I delete, which I did)

```
frame = Chop@First@ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 10];

Graphics3D[{frame, GeometricTransformation[frame, {{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, {5, 5, 0}}]}]
```

(and I still don't understand the Chop@First@ part)

**Last comment for tonight (Spanish time)**

Actually, I may have solved the $tmin$, $tmax$ problem, but I'd like to *see* the pictures to confirm!

Idea: consider the sphere as define by the dot product of the vector p (I think I swapped my frames around, but it doesn't really matter) transform the vector back to the other frame and solve (my copy/paste may be screwed up and it's late, but I hope you get the idea)

```
v = {vx, vy, vz}; (* assign velocity components *)
sphere[p_] := Sum[p[[i]]^2, {i, 1, Length[p]}]; (* define a sphere by magnitude of p*)
p0 = {t0, 0, 0, 0}; 
s = Simplify[sphere[LorentzF[-v].p0]];
solns = Solve[s == b, t0]; Simplify[solns]
```

Getting: (sorry, don't know how to do this nicely)

```
{{t0 -> -(Sqrt[b]/Sqrt[-((1 + vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2)/(-1 + vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2))])}, {t0 -> Sqrt[b]/Sqrt[-((1 + vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2)/(-1 + vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2))]}}
```

which seemed OK (too) late last night, but now doesn't. Hence my confusions

It would have been nice if I could have found a way to create a substitution `V^2=vx^2+vy^2+vz^2` but `V^2` can't be a symbol (?)

Comment: You're going to need to post code showing some minimal attempt(s) at this, in general this is not a internet-based code-for-free sweatshop...

Comment: I've spent two full days at this so far; I will gladly share the failure in further detail tomorrow. I thought I was being considerate by omitting my garbage!

Comment: You might want to ask on physics.SE *how* to represent this, since you seem to be unsure whether you want an ellipsoid or how the sphere is deformed.  If I knew what you wanted *Mma* to draw, I'm pretty sure someone here could help you do that.

Comment: @Michael, I may try that too, but it's not a question of whether I "want" an ellipsoid, I'd like to confirm (or refute) my intuition; this is just one part of a much bigger question and I'm happy with the SR theory it's how to handle the equations effectively in Mma I'm really struggling with. To be brief, of course in A the sphere is going to appear contracted along the direction of motion (and not perpendicular to it), it's the temporal aspect that is of greater interest at the moment - and I would lik to produce some robust figures for an outline of a paper.

Comment: @JulianMoore take a look at [structure of graphics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32716/how-to-examine-the-structure-of-graphics-objects) to see why there is `First`. `Chop` is not necessary, it only makes `10^-17` be `0` etc.

Comment: Thanks again Kuba (and for tidying up the question); I was slowly working it all out. I have since managed to do pretty much what I wanted (confirming intuition) based on transformation of a parametric approach (considered, rejected, reconsidered on the basis of your example). Now I know more, reading the docs will be far more meaningful. Structure of graphics is close to the top of the list. I'm kinda glad I've worked it out for myself mostly, but really appreciate input given in making me look more closely at certain things. Interestingly, this type of problem is still generating papers...