# Short form of Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, version-10

Sometimes I want to investigate the structure of `Graphics`/`Graphics3D` which is produced by `Plot`/`Plot3D` or similar command. Often `InputForm` produces a very big output

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // InputForm
(* Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Directive[Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 
      0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], Line[{{2.040816326530612*^-8, 
     2.040816326530612*^-8}, {0.000306717908041361, 0.000306717908041361},
     ... points, points, points ...
     {0.9999999795918367, 0.9999999795918367}}]}}}, 
 {DisplayFunction -> Identity, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), 
  Axes -> {True, True}, AxesLabel -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  DisplayFunction :> Identity, Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  GridLines -> {None, None}, GridLinesStyle -> 
   Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
  Method -> {"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic, 
    "ScalingFunctions" -> None}, PlotRange -> 
   {{0, 1}, {0., 0.9999999795918367}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, 
    {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}] *)
```

*What is the simplest way to get a small and informative output?*

For example, in version 9 and earlier I can use `` // InputForm // Developer`PackedArrayForm ``

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // InputForm // Developer`PackedArrayForm

(* Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], 
 Line["PackedArray"[Real, "<"77","2">"]]}}}, 
 {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {None, None},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Method -> {}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0., 0.9999999795918367}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}] *)
```

I see all options and I see the dimensions of a big data arrays. It is not the case for `Short` or `Shallow`

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // InputForm // Short
(* Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Directive[<<3>>], Line[{<<77>>}]}}}, {<<16>>}] *)
```

However, in V10 `` Developer`PackedArrayForm `` produces a mess with `InputForm`

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // InputForm // Developer`PackedArrayForm
(* Graphics[{{{}, {}, {Directive[Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
 AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], Line["PackedArray"[Real, Row[{Style["<",
    ShowStringCharacters -> False, StripOnInput -> True], Row[{77, 
    Style[",", ShowStringCharacters -> False], 2}, StripOnInput -> True],
    Style[">", ShowStringCharacters -> False, StripOnInput -> True]},
    StripOnInput -> True]]]}}}, 
{DisplayFunction -> Identity, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> {True, True}, 
AxesLabel -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, DisplayFunction :> Identity, 
Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}, FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
GridLines -> {None, None}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
Method -> {"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic, "ScalingFunctions" -> None}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0., 0.9999999795918367}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.05], Scaled[0.05]}}, 
Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}] *)
```

Could you propose an alternative approach? May be I miss something very simple. I don't want to write a complicated parser. The main goal is to do it as fast and simple as possible.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32716/5478)

Comment: How about `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // InputForm // Short`? Or, if you need more control, `Short[InputForm[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]], 10]`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure As I show in the post, it hides the options. Options are more significant for the graphics then the particular values of the data. It is not convenient to find every time a threshold for `Short` which will show the options and do not show a lot of points.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a comment since I looked at your post quite quickly.  Does `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // Options` help?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Sometimes it can help. However, suddenly I find a simple solution, which I posted as the answer.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I remembered this thread, but it mainly devoted to writing complicated parsers and the visual representation of the structure.

Comment: @ybeltukov I agree, just wanted to link for visitors :)

Answer (score 7):

I find a simple version-independent solution, which produces a very clear output

```
List @@ Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // Developer`PackedArrayForm
```

[image]

Moreover, it allows a brackets-matching and a multiple-click highlighting!

Answer (score 5):

```
show = {Short@First@#, Last@#} &;

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}] // show
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I added the snapshot. I hope you don't mind.