# How can I set PlotStyle for Show?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Consider:

```
pltabsall = Show[
  pltAbs1001, pltAbs1005, pltAbs1006, pltAbs1007, pltAbs1008,
  pltAbs1009, pltAbs1010, pltAbs1011, pltAbs1012, pltAbs1013,
  pltAbs1014, pltAbs1015, pltAbs1016, pltAbs1017, pltAbs1018,
  pltAbs1019, pltAbs1020, pltAbs1021, pltAbs1022, pltAbs1022,
  pltAbs1023, pltAbs1024, pltAbs1025, pltAbs1026, pltAbs1027,
  pltAbs1028, pltAbs1029, pltAbs1030, pltAbs1031, pltAbs1034,
  pltAbs1035, pltAbs1036, pltAbs1037, pltAbs1039, pltAbs1040,
  pltAbs1041]
```

Each `plt` is a plot, and I want to use `Show` and to automatic change plotstyle for all subplots, i.e. the color of each trace; is it possible? Without changing the settings from inside of PltAbs10xx?

[image]

Comment: Why couldn't you set `PlotStyle` in each of the `pltAbs` objects?

Comment: It is not clear, what do you want to achieve. Do you need to vary all plot styles simultaneously, or separately for different plts? Dynamically, or by multiple evaluations? What about this approach: `a = {Thin, Dashed}; b = {Red, Dotted}; Show[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> a],  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> b]}]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Graphics` objects from `Plot` has a `Directive`, which act as the `PlotStyle`. Changing that would give you the desired result.

For instance:

```
Show[{fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6, fn7, fn8, fn9, fn10}]
```

[image]

```
Show[{fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6, fn7, fn8, fn9, fn10}/. Directive[__] -> Red]
```

[image]

If you want different colors for each function, use functions like `Hue` (as shown here) or `ColorData`, etc.

```
Show[Table[
 ReplaceAll[#[[n]], Directive[__] -> Hue[(n-1)/(Length[#] - 1)]], {n, 
  Length[#]}] &@{fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6, fn7, fn8, fn9, 
   fn10}]
```

[image]

You add more options if you use `Directive`. e.g. `Thick`:

```
Show[Table[
 ReplaceAll[#[[n]], Directive[__] -> 
   Directive[Thick, Hue[(n - 1)/(Length[#] - 1)]]], {n, 
   Length[#]}] &@{fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6, fn7, fn8, fn9, 
    fn10}]
```

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend using a `Part` specification to extract the elements unless you had _no other choice_ since they are not guaranteed to stay the same from release to release. But, there are plenty of other choices, like Jason's [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114784/52), above. At worst, you could flatten the structure using `parser@Normal@plot` with this [parser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32719/52).

Comment: @rcollyer silly me, I didn't think of that. Changed my answer to use `ReplaceAll` and not `ReplacePart`. This will work, wouldn't it?

Comment: You could use `Directive[__]`, but then you're changing other aspects of the style that you might not want to change. I think I'd use `_?ColorQ -> Red` (provided you have v10) as it is more specific for this case. (+1 for being a reasonable idea, now) Other notes: check out [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html), it will work better than `Table[...]& @ {...}`.

Comment: @rcollyer `GridLinesStyle` uses `Directive` as well, so `ReplaceAll` will change that. However, `_?ColorQ -> Red` can also change it... In my `Table[]`, I needed the length of the input list, so I decided not to use `MapIndexed`. Nothing is more confusing than two layers of pure functions!

Comment: Right, if you want to change `GridLinesStyle`, then definitely replace `Directive`. I like `ColorQ` because it is nice and focused, but sometimes it is to focused. As far as layers of pure functions, I've done worse then two layers. I used to be a fan of chaining pure functions together through postfix (`//`), 10 or even 20 functions wasn't abnormal, and a complete nightmare to debug a week later when I needed to change something. :)

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent it changing my axis colour too? Also it gets too colorful and nothing is visible lol

Answer (score 14):

You have a list of plots that you have defined already, all using the default color,

```
(Evaluate[Symbol["plt" <> IntegerString[#]]] = 
     Plot[# x^2, {x, -3, 3}]) & /@ Range[7];
Show[{plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6, plt7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Boy that doesn't look right, so let's see if we can change that.  Changing the color on any one plot is easy,

```
plt1 /. {{a__, Line[b__]} :> {a, Red, Line[b]}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(I'm pretty sure there's a way to write that pattern without letters, but I don't know it)

To apply this to a list of plots, one way is to use `MapIndexed`,

```
Show[
 MapIndexed[#1 /. {{a__, Line[b__]} :> {a, ColorData[97, First@#2], 
       Line[b]}} &, {plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6, plt7}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could do other things, like make every other line dashed,

```
Show[
 MapIndexed[#1 /. {{a__, Line[b__]} :> {a, ColorData[97, First@#2], 
       Dashing[If[EvenQ[First@#2], .01, {}]], Line[b]}} &, {plt1, 
   plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6, plt7}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OK ... JasonB we have to talk about speed! +1

Comment: The key is that I have a neural implant designed to go off when a question with one of my favorite tags is posted.  :-)

Comment: Hey Jason, could you please explain the code? I don't really understand how MapIndexed works here. Thanks!

Comment: MapIndexed[#1 /. {{a__, Point[b__]} :> {a, ColorData[108, First@#2], 
      Point[b]}} &, 
 Graphics[{Point[Table[{ii, 0}, {ii, 10}]]}]] Why this does not work?

Comment: @Mikayel - I'm using MapIndexed here to directly modify the `Graphics` expression.  To do that you have to know what your `Graphics` looks like in order to do pattern replacements.  In the code you pasted, there isn't anything to match the `{a__, Point[b__]}` pattern.