# Individual synchronized point/line coloring

Tags: plotting, color

This is a extension to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114782/how-can-i-set-plotstyle-for-show/114786#114786) and the answer from Jason B.

Consider a list of plots

```
    (Evaluate[Symbol["plt" <> IntegerString[#]]] = 
     Plot[(x - 4*# + 16)^2, {x, -20, 20}]) & /@ Range[7];
    Show[{plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6, plt7}]
```

[image]

Say, we want to change the color of the plots, which are previously defined. Here is the solution from Jason.

```
Show[MapIndexed[#1 /. {{a__, Line[b__]} :> {a, 
   ColorData[97, First@#2], Line[b]}} &, {plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4,plt5, plt6, plt7}], Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Point[Table[{-16 + 4*ii, 0}, {ii, 7}]]}] ]
```

[image]

Now, suppose we need to add some points to the plot (see Fig. above) so that every point corresponds to a plot. How do I make the colors of the points to match the colors of the corresponding plots?

Comment: You can put it in: `{a,  ColorData[97, First@#2], Line[b]}}`. `#2` is an index of a plot so you can use it to extract expected point from your list.

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[MapIndexed[#1 /. {{a__, Line[b__]} :> {a, 
       ColorData[97, First@#2], Line[b]}} &, {plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6, plt7}], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Table[{ColorData[97, ii], Point@{-16 + 4*ii, 0}}, {ii, 7}]}]]
```

or

```
Show[MapIndexed[#1 /. {{a__, Line[b__]} :> {a, 
   ColorData[97, First@#2], Line[b], PointSize[.02], Point@{-16 + 4* First@#2 , 0} }} &, 
 {plt1, plt2, plt3, plt4, plt5, plt6, plt7}] ]
```

[image]