# How to force 2=={} as a Boolean output?

Tags: output-formatting, boolean-computation, logic

I have a code as below:-

```
x = 2;
If[x == {}, 1, 0]
```

I want the output to be `0`, but the output I got is the entire `If[2 == {}, 1, 0]`. How can I force `2 == {}` to be `False`?

Many thanks!

Comment: Would `SameQ`, aka `===` be sufficient for you? It has its own quirks, for instance it can't delay evaluation, but instead falls on such cases to `False`, and treats numbers like `0` and `0.` as different.

Comment: Note that you could use the 4th argument of `If` which is returned when the condition is neither `False` nor `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `===`. That tests if things are the same.

Comment: Or `If[TrueQ[x == {}], 1, 0]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `TrueQ` is good, as long as one remembers that there are situations where getting `False` as a result instead of getting delayed evaluation expression is actually a bad thing. I wonder why comparison of clearly different inputs fails gets delayed in this way, though...

Comment: @kirma I think `Equals` is somewhat agnostic to what we deem clear differences. For example, `2 == {}` could potentially evaluate, i.e. `List[]`, via `Block`, could be given a value. So, it makes sense to not evaluate it. On the other hand, `SameQ` tests for structurally equivalence. Clearly there is a middle ground here, and I often have to define an equivalence test for different structures, such as with the results of a [parser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32719/52).